# Portable Guitar Amp - Distortion, Volume & GND

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, lm386, dip, guitar-amplifier

I have tried following the given schematic [image: SCHEMATIC OF GUITAR AMP]

There are 3 things I am unsure of (what I tried):

- The Volume 5k Potentiometer:
  I have tried adding a volume control to the schematic by placing the potentiometer parallel to the Dip Switch. But i am unsure whether this is what has to be done. Could someone help me clarify this?
- The Distortion, The instructions stated that we could go up to 10uF but i have added an 8 tone dip switch with 22, 33 and 47 uF additional capacitors. Is this acceptable?
- The GND
  I am completely unsure how to connect the earthing (ground). Do i connect the negative wire to the GND but wouldnt that just short the sleeve and the ring according to the schematic...
  EDIT: As indicated by Anonymous, the shortage will provide the GND.

I also added an led paired with a 470Ohm resistor parallel to the inputs to indicate whether it is working or not.

I am a novice guitar player and wanted to build a 0.5-1W amplifier for the same. but i have little previous experience in Electronics. I would be immensely grateful if somebody could guide me and help me out on this.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Regarding third point: it seems amplifier it expected to turn on when mono TRS (called TS) connector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio) is inserted into input jack shorting `-` of the battery to `GND` and thus providing power to the amplifier. Inserting stereo jack will not turn it on, and even may damage something "at the other end" of input cable connected between ring and sleeve.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks loads, now i understand why my circuit was not functioning at all..